# generating list/array from a text file in LUA

Tags: arrays, string, list, lua

I'm trying to handle a text file containing a list of numbers (generated from a python script) into a LUA script.

the text file contain this (I formatted it in the python script to match the list syntax of LUA) :

```
{"0.0", "0.1", "0.2", "0.3", "0.4", "0.5", "0.6", "0.7", "0.8", "0.9", "1.0", "834.3", "1667.6", "2500.9", "3334.2", "4167.5", "5000.8", "5834.1", "6667.4", "7500.7", "8334.0", "9167.3", "10000.6", "10833.9", "11667.2", "12500.5", "13333.8", "14167.1", "15000.4", "15833.7", "16667.0", "17500.3", "18333.6", "19166.9", "20000.2", "20833.5", "21666.8", "22500.1", "23333.4", "24166.7", "25000.0", "22244444.44", "44463888.89", "66683333.33", "88902777.78", "111122222.22", "133341666.67", "155561111.11", "177780555.56", "200000000.0", }
```

However when I try to read it in LUA, first I use this command (where "params.style_weight_list" is a link to the text file previously generated) :

```
print("SW LIST = ",params.style_weight_list)
```

which gives me this result :

```
SW LIST =   {"0.0", "0.1", "0.2", "0.3", "0.4", "0.5", "0.6", "0.7", "0.8", "0.9", "1.0", "834.3", "1667.6", "2500.9", "3334.2", "4167.5", "5000.8", "5834.1", "6667.4", "7500.7", "8334.0", "9167.3", "10000.6", "10833.9", "11667.2", "12500.5", "13333.8", "14167.1", "15000.4", "15833.7", "16667.0", "17500.3", "18333.6", "19166.9", "20000.2", "20833.5", "21666.8", "22500.1", "23333.4", "24166.7", "25000.0", "22244444.44", "44463888.89", "66683333.33", "88902777.78", "111122222.22", "133341666.67", "155561111.11", "177780555.56", "200000000.0", }
```

yet everything seems good (there is several blank spaces before the first bracket, don't know why though)

but when I try to access a specific item from the list this way (frameIdx is an int) :

```
local neu_sw = params.style_weight_list[frameIdx]
```

it return a nil value, so I think I got to convert the imported list from a string to a proper usable list in LUA but don't know how? Anybody has an idea?

Comment: If you change the python output to create a valid lua file you can call `require` on that file, or load it using `loadfile`

Answer (score 0):

When you're unsure what's happening in the script you can always debug the code.

1. Use `print` and `type` to see what value you have and what its type is.
2. Inspect your table with `for k,v in pairs(tbl) do print(k,v) end` to see if it really has that key.

As I can see, `params.style_weight_list` is not a table but a string. You can use `load` to convert string into script with a Lua table, `loadfile` to read it from a file directly (or with `require`, this requires you to prepend `return`  at the beginning of the file), or make a parser that reads values (more proper way but complicated for beginners)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help Nifim and Spar !

thanks to your insight I got it working. if this can help, here what I did :

- export my python array into a txt file ( with a lua extension, probably useless but helped me keeping it clear in my folder) with one value by line and no other formating elements.
  "a" is my array in python.

  LUA_in = n*'{}\n' 
  LUA_format = LUA_in.format(*a)
  LUA_file = open("sw.lua","w")
  LUA_file.write(LUA_format)
- and then read it in lua, create an empty table, add one value/line per table lines and read the specific line I need.

  sw_array = {}
  for line in io.lines("sw.lua") do
  table.insert(sw_array, line)
  end

  local cur_sw = sw_array[frameIdx+1]

where frameIdx is the specific value Index I want to read (and "+1" because lua tables start counting from 1 and python from 0)